# Use javascript to replace .show() for an image with a class

Tags: javascript

For a jquery plugin to work I have to set the **img** with the **class lazy** to **display: none** from CSS.

I know how to make it appear when I need it using jquery:

```
$("img.lazy").show();
```

The problem is that I am loading the jquery library in the footer and I need the image to appear when the page starts to load.

I cannot move the code to the header cause there is no jquery.

So I am thinking of doing it with javascript.

I have tried getElementbyID but I can't make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you rearrange your `<script>` tags?

Comment: Why not just setting it display:block from the start? Or I'm not getting what you're trying to do....

Comment: Read that its better to load jquery at the bottom of the page, speed wize. Should I load it on top, in header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following to display all images with class name `lazy` using `querySelectorAll`

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy");
for(i=0;i<el.length;i++) el[i].style.display='block';
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HauvK/1/).

For single element you can use `querySelector`

```
var el = document.querySelector("img.lazy"); // only one/the first img with class name lazy
el.style.display='block';
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HauvK/2/).

[**Browser compatibility for querySelector/querySelectorAll**](http://caniuse.com/queryselector).

Alternative (runs in every browser)

```
​var els=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
if(els)
{
    for(i=0;i<els.length;i++)
    {
        if(els[i].className.match(/lazy/)) els[i].style.display='block';
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A7vb5/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have an Id attribute on your element,

```
document.getElementById("YourId").style.display = "block"; //or inline
```

Should work just fine.

`querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByClassName` are also options if you are willing/able to neglect older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript. It is jQuery independent, just as you asked. This solution [won't work in IE8 and less](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName('lazy');

  for (var i = 0; i <= images.length - 1; i++) {
    images.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
```

If you wan't IE support for this, then you will need to give your images unique IDs and select them like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('lazy').style.display = 'block';
};
```

Or the jQuery method, even if your `<script>` is in the footer (after you load the jQuery library, of course):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img.lazy').show();
});
```

**Quick note:** Loading jQuery (or any JavaScript) at the bottom of the page doesn't decrease load time, but the perceived load time. The web browser still must load the same amount of content, it's just that the bulky JS files are loaded after the visible content of the page. I don't have a problem including  tags in the .

Comment: That was me, sorry for not explaining, you are neglecting to mention the lack of support for that DOM method in non-modern browsers.  If that were a viable solution we wouldn't require frameworks like JQuery.

Comment: @marteljn No probs. Thanks for explaining. I though IE6 and up supported `getElementsByClassName`, I just found out its IE9 and up. (GRRR IE....) You're right bad suggestion. Let me fix it. :)

Comment: @marteljn I just realized that I was stealing your thunder, my bad. +1 as your solution is a good one.

Comment: No worries, not a bad solution, just needed to include the fine print:)